# Shortest way to rendering Javascript output as markup in Adobe Experience Manager?

Tags: javascript, adobe, aem, sightly, htl

I must (project requirement) create some markup directly in Javascript on the server side and then integrate it into the HTL output without further modification.

The following two-liner works for me:

```
<sly data-sly-use.markup="${'render.js'}" />
${markup @ context='unsafe'}
```

But I am wondering if there is a way to shorten it further?

In the Adobe documentation I find other `sly-` block statements like `sly-template` and `sly-resource` that can include the output of some other HTL or JSP file directly, but is the same also possible with a Javascript file?

Like this:

```
<sly data-sly-magicmagicmagic="${'render.js'}" />
```

?

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no such `thingamajig` ;)

You can however write it a bit nicer as

```
<sly data-sly-use.markup="${'render.js'}">${markup @ context='unsafe'}</sly>
```

I stronly suggest you use the `html` context though.